# Adding additional information for logging data with enterprise library

Tags: c#, enterprise-library

I have configured enterprise library to log data into the database and everything works just fine. This is how the curent logging information looks like:

> Timestamp: 6/19/2013 7:10:01 AM
>
> Category: eConnect Exception
>
> Priority: 0
>
> EventId: 100
>
> Severity: Error
>
> Title:Enterprise Library Exception Handling
>
> Machine: ISDC30517
>
> App Domain: /LM/W3SVC/23/ROOT-4-130160992152908413
>
> ProcessId: 8808
>
> Process Name: C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe
>
> Thread Name:
>
> Win32 ThreadId:8952
>
> Extended Properties:

This is the code that logs my exceptions at the momment:

```
public void LogException(Exception exception)
{
   ExceptionPolicy.HandleException(exception, "GeneralExceptionPolicy");
}
```

The default script that I have run to generate the database tables for Enterprise Library to log data generates for each property that I have mentioned a new column.

Now I would like to also be able to add additional information.At the moment I am thinking of adding the user name of the Current User that got this exception.

I have searched a lot and I can not seem to find something that can assist me in this.How can I add additional information to the logged message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the additional information to the Exception.Data property.  These values will be added to the LogEntry's ExtendedProperties.  You can then configure the formatter to output the specific Extended Property keys in the formattedMessage string.  See: [Exception.Data info is missing in EntLib log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291619/exception-data-info-is-missing-in-entlib-log)

That's probably the easiest way but then the information is buried within a string in the database table.

Another approach would be to add the data directly to the database.  This will involve changes to the out of the box database schema and stored procedures as well as creation of a custom trace listener.  You can find two different designs at the [Enterprise Library Sample Projects](http://entlib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Sample%20Projects&referringTitle=Home) page:

- The Extended Properties Trace Listener with Custom Exception Handler contains a custom trace listener that logs extended properties to a separate extended properties table which allows all extended properties to be written.
- The Custom Database Trace Listener Sample uses a CustomLogEntry to write some CustomData into a custom database column on the Log table.